# How to create Virtual servers in IBM cloud Terraform with for loop?

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, terraform-provider-ibm

I have a Virtual server in IBM cloud created using Terraform

```
resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi1" {
  name    = "${local.BASENAME}-vsi1"
  vpc     = ibm_is_vpc.vpc.id
  zone    = local.ZONE
  keys    = [data.ibm_is_ssh_key.ssh_key_id.id]
  image   = data.ibm_is_image.ubuntu.id
  profile = "cc1-2x4"

  primary_network_interface {
    subnet          = ibm_is_subnet.subnet1.id
    security_groups = [ibm_is_security_group.sg1.id]
  }
}
```

How to create Virtual Servers with Terraform For loops

```
vsi1 , vsi2, vsi3, vsi4, vsi5
```

for full code Please refer [IBM Cloud Terraform getting started tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-getting-started)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not require a `for` or `for-each` loop for achieving what you need. A simple `count` will do the required. Once you add count(number of instances), all you need to do is pass `count.index` in the VSI name.

```
resource "ibm_is_instance" "vsi" {
  count   = 4
  name    = "${local.BASENAME}-vsi-${count.index}"
  vpc     = ibm_is_vpc.vpc.id
  zone    = local.ZONE
  keys    = [data.ibm_is_ssh_key.ssh_key_id.id]
  image   = data.ibm_is_image.ubuntu.id
  profile = "cc1-2x4"

  primary_network_interface {
    subnet          = ibm_is_subnet.subnet1.id
    security_groups = [ibm_is_security_group.sg1.id]
  }
}
```

This will create instances with names vsi-0,vsi-1...